# OR operator in json-server

Tags: javascript, json, npm, json-server

I can fetch data from json-server (fake server) by calling:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?title_like=head&comments_like=today
```

This will return records where title likes "head" `AND` comments like "today".
What if I want not `AND` but `OR` operator?

Comment: but how? it's fake json-server

Comment: You'll probably need to use a custom [route/middleware](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes) to handle this.

Comment: I can't understand how they can help me out

Comment: Have you figured out a way yet? I'm also struggling with this :(

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement routes, just like @lewis mentioned too. If you haven't implemented routes yet, maybe it is a good place to start (if you have to provide inputs in a URL).

"...title_like=head&comments_like=today" is just a URL, and I do not believe URL is best place to specify "OR" logic. It should be up to your server side code to decide whether or not to use "AND" or "OR" logic between provided parameters.

If you did end up using above URL, and server side code did in fact implement an "OR" logic, your clients may get confused, because they maybe expecting "AND" behavior, especially if they did not read your documentation.

Another alternative is to provide inputs in a body parameter, instead of a URL. Body parameter can be and are used for both "AND" and "OR" logic.  That way you can also communicate to your users that both values from the body will be used for "OR" logic, not "AND" logic (again, if your clients do read the documentation)

Comment: I know what you are saying, but I need concrete way of implementation in case of json-server: https://github.com/typicode/json-server